# How can I round a Decimal value upto a precision so that the total number of digits doesnot cross 15?

Tags: c#, excel, math, openxml-sdk

I need to round values like 25979.699999999997 to 15 digits so it becomes 25979.7 and does not contain any insignificant zeroes.

Background:
I am trying to parse an excel file using OpenXML SDK, and there a decimal value such as 25979.7 is read as 25979.699999999997.

When MS excel shows the value, it always rounds them to 15 digits and removes trailing zeroes so it becomes 25979.7, but when I am reading using OpenXML SDK it does not do that automatically.

Any idea?

EDIT: Actually I don't want to modify the value, just want to **display** in that format(as a string).

Comment: I think that `Double` will have 15 digit precision  Also `The Decimal structure is strictly geared to financial calculations requiring accuracy, which are relatively intolerant of rounding.`

Comment: Are you sure you want to **round** i.e. modify the value, OR just **display** in a nice format?

Comment: He's asking for 15 total digits, so 25979.699999999997 -> 25979.7000000000 -> 25979.7.

Comment: @DrKoch you are right, I want to display this in a nice format. I have been trying different formats like this-  
Decimal.Parse("25979.699999999997").ToString("#0.#0");
or Decimal.Parse("25979.699999999997").ToString("#.#0");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply format your (umodified) value to get a nicly formated string:

```
double val = double.Parse("25979.699999999997");
string formatted = val.ToString("g");
```

The `g` formatting will do all the work for you.

Comment: Thank You! That actually works! One thing I'm still tempted to ask that will save me from making some unwelcomed changes in my code, that- can I use Decimal values to be parsed like that rather than using Double? Following returns 25979.699999999997 when use I decimal:
Decimal.Parse("25979.699999999997").ToString("g")

Comment: Well, as @methodman mentioned, `decimal` is actually designed to preserve precission, simplified: it thinks you want all these: ...99997

Comment: This only works by dint of the fact that `double` has around the same amount of precision that Thunderstruck wants.

Comment: Well, OP probably wants this precision, because Excel has double precsision, about 15 digits...

Comment: Thank you all. @Rawling Yes you are right, I want that exact same amount of precision that's why this solution would work for me :) And your comment made the whole scenario more clear to me. The problem started when we had a problem of parsing numeric values from excel, the precision of > 8 were getting lost, we found that was due to using float, and moved to using Decimal instead. Didn't notice until now, now that I know Excel inherently uses Double, we should use Double too.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can try not so complicated math:

```
var x = 25979.699999999997;
var y = Math.Round(x, 15 - (int)Math.Floor(Math.Log10(x) + 1));
```

`y` will be exactly 25979.7

Here we calculating number of digits before decimal separator as

```
Math.Floor(Math.Log10(x) + 1)
```

and subtracting it from 15 gives us remaining fractional digits to round to.

Comment: It looks like OP is using the `decimal` type, in which case rounding will actually preserve the trailing zeroes.

Comment: @Rawling not sure if I've understood you correctly - but the only problem with decimal I can see here - is the fact that `Math.Log10` has `double` as argument - so ugly cast is needed, but in this particular case this cast is not a problem.

Comment: In the example given, the result of rounding the decimal will be `25979.7000000000`. A decimal is aware of how precise it is and preserves trailing zeroes. If you call `ToString()` on a decimal, those zeroes are printed by default.

Comment: @Rawling Oh, I got your point... it was not specified explicitly in original question that OP wants just to display value, so I was not bothered about `ToString`

Comment: To account for numbers smaller than 1 you need to replace `Math.Log10(x)` with `Math.Max(Math.Log10(x), 0)`.